# I can't get GitBook mermaid plugin to work, what a, i doing wrong?

Tags: gitbook, mermaid

I'm new at Gitbook and can not get the mermaid plugin to work.

book.json

```
{
"plugins": ["mermaid-2"
          ],
"pluginsConfig": {
  "mermaid-2": {
     "theme": "forest"
              }
} }
```

file.md : I put the code into fenced code block and tag it mermaid

```
mermaid
graph TD;
A-->B;
A-->C;
B-->D;
C-->D;
```

But it is not showing diagrams, it display as:

```
graph TD;
A-->B;
A-->C;
B-->D;
C-->D;
```

Please help me, why is this not working?

Answer (score 1):

Since gitbook-plugin-mermaid-2 does not work as it is, you need to edit node_modules/gitbook-plugin-mermaid-2/index.js as below.(Around line 33)

```
js: [
  'bower_components/mermaid/dist/mermaid.min.js',
  'plugin.js'
]
```

then surround file.md with ```mermaid.